# How to check two queries and then show the result?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting data from firebase and that part is working fine but when I put two different queries then it display the following error and ask me to create index in firestore but the index is already there. And if I try to fetch the data only with one query then it works fine, no matter which query it is both show the result accordingly. And I want to check two queries simultaneously and then show the result.

Error:-

```
W/Firestore(30122): (23.0.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users where isOnline == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@8bb4a
W/Firestore(30122): boolean_value: true
W/Firestore(30122): integer_value: 0 and age >= # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@90282
W/Firestore(30122): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(30122): string_value: "18" and age <= # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@91a86
W/Firestore(30122): integer_value: 0
W/Firestore(30122): string_value: "50" order by age, __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/practiceflutter-692db/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClNwcm9qZWN0cy9wcmFjdGljZWZsdXR0ZXItNjkyZGIvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL3VzZXJzL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgwKCGlzT25saW5lEAEaBwoDYWdlEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ, cause=null}
E/flutter (30122): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/practiceflutter-692db/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClNwcm9qZWN0cy9wcmFjdGljZWZsdXR0ZXItNjkyZGIvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL3VzZXJzL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgwKCGlzT25saW5lEAEaBwoDYWdlEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ
E/flutter (30122): #0      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (30122): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30122): #1      Query.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:177:9)
E/flutter (30122): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30122):
```

if I remove **.where('isOnline',isEqualTo: true)** then it works fine or only check **.where('isOnline',isEqualTo: true)** then also it show the result accordingly. And I want it to check both and then proceed. Query I am trying is:-

```
query() {

    if (currentUser.showGender == 'everyone') {
      return _reference.where('isOnline',isEqualTo: true)
          .where('age',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: currentUser.ageRange['min'],
      )
          .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo:currentUser.ageRange['max'])
          .orderBy('age', descending: false).limit(docLimit);
    } else {
      return _reference.where('isOnline',isEqualTo: true)
          .where('editInfo.userGender', isEqualTo: currentUser.showGender)
          .where('age',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:currentUser.ageRange['min'],
      )
          .where('age',
          isLessThanOrEqualTo: currentUser.ageRange['max'])
          .orderBy('age', descending: false).limit(docLimit);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you require and index. The error also provides a direct URL to do so.

> https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/practiceflutter-692db/firestore/indexes?create_composite=<random_hash>

Please follow the URL and create the relevant index.

[image]

Comment: but index is already there and if I only check with one query then  there is no such error.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH can you please share a screenshot of the index that you already have?

Comment: @GAGANSINGH can you please create an index as in my updated answer?

Comment: I deleted the isOnline old index and then tried to create like you said but then I am getting error => index already exists.

Comment: Do I need to delete all the indexes and then create the single one like you said? because I am using the userGender index in other screens also. Hope it doesn't effect there where there it is already working fine.

Comment: new index has build but the error is still the same.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH can you open the link that you get in the error and share a screenshot of what index it tries to create ?

Comment: users isOnline Ascending age Ascending Collection  Enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234213/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-gagan-singh).

Comment: hey it worked now I think with above index. now getting no error as such let me check again. and thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH if the answer was helpful then you can accept/upvote so others will know it is resolved else feel free to ask further queries.